# When exporting numbers to CSV it become exponential

Tags: c#-4.0, export-to-csv, exponential

I developed a C# windows application which export some data from sql server as CSV file. Now I am facing issue with a number having more than 12 digit.
Instead of showing the number it is showing the exponential value.

like 1.4588E+12 instead of 1458795648552

How can i export the actual value instead of exponential.

Comment: You should show your code. In any case, the problem is quite clear: you are mixing-up number (which is always the same, up to the given precision) with string representation of such a number. If for example you have long val = 1458795648552; and you do val.ToString(), you wouldn't have any control over how the given value is shown (i.e., the default format in that given moment). When printing/converting to string numeric values, you should make sure that the given format is exactly as expected. One way to take care of this issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
var someDecimal = 1458795648552m;
var value = String.Format("{0:N}", someDecimal); // 1,458,795,648,552.00
var value2 = string.Format("{0:##################}", someDecimal);//1458795648552
```

[etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx)..